# Возможность авторизации запросов в spring и access_token-ом и через форму входа в браузере

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot, spring-security

**Дано:**

Проект на `spring`+`kotlin`. Реализовано получение `access_token` через БД и доступ к ресурсам с его помощью.

**Задача:**

Реализовать возможность доступа к ресурсам для юзеров, залогинившихся через форму логина в браузере.

**Проблема:**

Работает только один из способов авторизации. Если добавить аннотацию `@EnableResourceServer` - работает способ доступа с токеном. При запросе любой страницы в браузере просто выводит ошибку "неавторизован", в т.ч. по адресу `/login`. Если на `/login` зайти с прикреплением токена - выведет `404`. Если аннотацию `@EnableResourceServer` убрать - работает доступ через форму логина в браузере и получение токена, но все запросы с прикреплением токена перенаправляют на `/login`, т.е. токен не воспринимается.

**Вопрос:**

Как же сделать так, чтобы работало?

По идее надо написать что-то тут, но часы гугленья не дали понимания что именно:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean
    fun authenticationProvider(): DaoAuthenticationProvider {
        val authenticationProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        return authenticationProvider
    }

    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userDetailsService: UserServiceImpl

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
    }
}
```

**Дополнительная информация:**

Ссылка на весь проект на `GitHub`: https://github.com/mohaxspb/springSecurityExample/tree/v0.0.1

Для запуска и работы надо поставить `postgresql` и создать там под юзером `postgres` с паролем `testtest` БД с именем `springbootdb` - далее при запуске в БД создана будет таблица с юзерами и туда будет добавлен юзер, под коим можно логиниться с логином `test@test.ru` и паролем `password`. Для получения токена надо указать **client_id**: `client_id` и **client_secret**: `client_secret` (эти данные также пишутся в БД при старте сервера)

Comment: Доступ с обоими видами аутентификации нужен для одних и тех же ресурсов? Или хватит варианта доступа с токеном только для некоторых url'ов?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Нужно чтобы было одинаково. Т.е. я могу, конечно, забить на стандартную форму логина спринга и запилить фронтенд, который будет получать токен и его использовать для запросов, но очень не хочется. Хочу сделать всё на спринге чтобы не пилить админку отдельно.

Comment: Это усложняет задачу. Было бы сильно проще, если бы Spring мог различать к каким запросам какую аутентификацию применять.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, жаль( Я думал, что можно сделать всё одинаково для всех и только по ролям юзеров делать ограничения... Т.е., получается, всякие админки на сайтах не пишутся даже в простейшем виде на спринге, а используют что-то типа ангуляра, который вызывает методы с токеном? Если так, то, получается, форма логина спринга это просто самый простой но редко используемый способ?

Comment: Не готов заявить о своей авторитетности в этом вопросе, возможно есть другие способы, но я в похожей ситуации разносил различающиеся методы аутентификации по разным url'ам или по заголовку `X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, мне приходил в голову вариант с деплоем 2 артефактов, различающихся наличием/отсутствием аннотации на один сервер но на разные порты. Это совсем костыль ведь, да? =) Кажется странным, что так как я хочу сделать спринг по умолчанию не разрешает(

Comment: Ага, выглядит очень костыльно :) Да 100% есть способ как-то прогонять запросы через цепочку аутентификаторов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, осталось понять как это сделать) Я со спрингом всего неделю дело имею, засим больше ничего кроме костылей не могу придумать)

Comment: Я с ним 12 лет, но постоянно натыкаюсь на что-то, чего ещё не знаю. Очень уж он обилен.

Comment: Ого! Т.е. если вы мне не поможете то надежды нет? :-)

Comment: Не исключено, что сейчас найдётся кто-нибудь, кто со Spring'ом полгода, но уже сталкивался с похожей ситуацией и знает простой ответ :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, будем надеяться)

Comment: Я со спрингом не знаком, и почти 12 лет на java не писал уже как. Но кажется тут описывается примерно то что вам нужно http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers.

Comment: Предполагаю, что вам нужно реализовать свой HttpSessionStrategy, который будет доставать сессию либо из кук, либо из хедеров. У меня стояла похожая задача, вот мой вариант HttpSessionStrategy: https://gist.github.com/gordeevnm/a7d0d28ec119bff552cf072f8cd7c476
Регистрировать его можно просто как бин:
`@Bean
 public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
  return new HeaderOrCookieSessionStrategy();
 }`

Comment: @НикитаГордеев, спасибо, это, наверное, полезно, но как спринг сможет понять, что вытащенный из заголовка токен нужно соотнести с юзером из БД? Кажется, спринг по умолчанию не сможет это понять...

Comment: @НикитаГордеев, оказалось, что всё гораздо сложнее) Только это добавление не поможет - по умолчанию `ResourceServer` прямо запрещает авторизацию куками. Т.е. надо ещё и это разрешить) В общем, вчера ночью я уже нашёл решение и сегодня вечером распишу в ответе всё подробно. Если кратко - убрал `@EnableResourceServer` и настроил фильтр, вытаскивающий токен из запроса (если он там есть), получающий из него объект аутентификации и объект юзера и прописывающий всё полученное в `SecurityContext`, что позволяет спрингу воспринимать запросы с токеном как авторизованные наравне с запросами с куками.

Comment: Кажется, всё это можно и проще сделать, с `@EnableResourceServer`, но пока и так сойдёт - главное что я понял как оно работает)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема решена. Заключалась она в том, что при добавлении аннотации `@EnableResourceServer` в цепочку фильтров для каждого запроса добавлялся `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`, в настройках которого по умолчанию включён явный запрет на аутентификацию с помощью `Cookie`, которые используются при входе через форму логина.

С другой стороны, если убрать аннотацию `@EnableResourceServer`, то фильтр `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` не будет добавлен и спринг не будет знать, что на запросы с токеном надо реагировать попыткой аутентификации по токену.

В итоге я сделал так:

1. Убрал аннотацию `@EnableResourceServer`.
2. Вручную добавил `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` в цепочку фильтров для каждого запроса указав ему, что можно пропускать запросы с аутентификацией с помощью `Cookie`
3. Этому фильтру установил `AuthenticationManager` типа `OAuth2AuthenticationManager`
4. `OAuth2AuthenticationManager` - это дополнительный `AuthenticationManager`, которому передана реализация `ClientDetailsService` (отвечает за предоставление данных о клиентском приложении для авторизации) и реализация `ResourceServerTokenServices`, которая превращает `access_token` в объект `Authentication` с типом `OAuth2Authentication`
5. Т.к. спрингу надо знать какой `AuthenticationManager` главный, надо дефолтный пометить аннотацией `@Primary`

Таким образом, когда спринг не находит в запросе куки или токен он перенаправляет на страницу логина. После ввода данных устанавливает в браузере куку и аутентифицирует запросы ею. Если же в запросе есть токен, то срабатывает добавленный фильтр и пытается по токену аутентифицировать запрос. В случае удачи устанавливает аутентификацию в `SecurityContext`.

В итоге реализация `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` выглядит так:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var clientDetailsService: ClientServiceImpl

    @Bean
    fun tokenServices() = AccessTokenServices()

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean
    fun authenticationProvider(): DaoAuthenticationProvider {
        val authenticationProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder())

        return authenticationProvider
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userDetailsService: UserServiceImpl

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }

    @Bean
    fun oauth2authenticationManager(): OAuth2AuthenticationManager {
        val authManager = OAuth2AuthenticationManager()
        authManager.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService)
        authManager.setTokenServices(tokenServices())

        return authManager
    }

    @Bean
    fun myOAuth2Filter(): Filter {
        val filter = OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter()
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(oauth2authenticationManager())
        //allow auth with cookies (not only with token)
        filter.setStateless(false)

        return filter
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
        http
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()

        http
                .addFilterBefore(
                        myOAuth2Filter(),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java
                )
    }
}
```

Весь код в [репозитории под тегом v0.03](https://github.com/mohaxspb/springSecurityExample/tree/v0.03)

---

Наверное, можно сократить код, корректно реализовав `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` и вернув `@EnableResourceServer`. Если получится - дополню ответ.