# Как насроить Spring REST API авторизацию через токен

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Я пишу свой первый проект на Java Spring REST API и VueJS. Еще есть основное приложение и мобильное приложение (мое приложение как дополнительный сервис, пользователь регистрируется в основном приложении).

Авторизация происходить так:

1. Пользователь заходит на мобильное приложение (в cookie генерируется
   токен).
2. Пользователь через мобильное приложение заходить на мой сервис.
3. Когда заходит на сервис фронт (vuejs) берет этот токен и отправляет
   запрос к бэкенду (Spring REST).
4. Бэкенд берет этот токен и отправляет запрос на основное приложение и
   берет данные пользователя.

Теперь  надо сделать так чтобы фронт (vuejs) и бэк (spring rest api) общались между собой с помощью токена.

Comment: Какой токен? Можете привести пример?

Comment: Когда первый раз заходить пользователь, бэкенд генерирует (или берет тот первоначальный токен) токен, потом отправляет во фронт, при последующем запросе фронт прикрепляет в headers этот токен чтобы получить доступ

Comment: Приведите экземпляр кода, который можно воспроизвести.

Comment: осмелюсь предположить что речь идет об oauth token

Comment: Да, наподобие этого

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть - может поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/810931/17609